# fetch user gallery on instagram without login on android

Tags: android, authentication, gallery, instagram

hey guys so im wondering whether there is a way to bring up a particular users gallery on android without going through authentication or logging in?

(i do currently have something but it runs through oAuth and requires the user to log in
thank you

Comment: Any feed that is public can be read.  Otherwise you just need to think about what you're asking ... can you see protected data without authenticating?  Probably not ;)

Comment: @Bill Mote yes it is a public user feed I just want to know how if go about reading it and creating the gallery in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this endpoint with `client_id`, login via oauth is not necessary:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/USER-ID/media/recent/?client_id=YOUR-CLIENT_ID
```

but your `app` will be limited to 5000 API calls per hour, if you ask users to login then `each user` will have 5000 calls/hour

Comment: so in my oAuth application i get as far as to authoriseing the logged user, it successfully grabs an access token but then tells me "failed to fetch user information" any ideas? am i typing the API url wrong or something?

Comment: if u have access_token then use : `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/USER-ID/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`